# Combine the row values with if it is nan in id section (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I Unable to find the solution, for how can we combine row text based on Nan Values with respect to id.

Below is the original data that I would like to combine.

[image: input data]

Below is what I am expecting the result.

[image: Expected Result]

Please if anyone find the solution that would be great help

Comment: is expected that the **ID** is the same across inputs and target?  Both examples **ID** is 21213  Paste your inputs as text not an image..

Comment: Hi, the ID will be the same or it will be different, I need the combined text if the ID section has "NaN" values and with respect to ID, it should fill. help me out on that thanks for your comments

Comment: Read the article why you shouldn't have to upload images and edit your questions into text based. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- given your **ID** column does not identify a target record,  I've taken approach of generating series `(~df["ID"].isna()).cumsum()` to find groups of rows
- with this it's then a simple `groupby().agg()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [21213.0, np.nan, np.nan, 21213.0, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Text': ['Voluptatem sed consectetur quisquam est.',
  'Quaerat quisquam modi consectetur.',
  'Est labore aliquam neque quaerat velit labore porro.',
  'Dolorem quisquam magnam labore amet amet sit sed.',
  'Magnam ut modi aliquam consectetur quisquam consectetur.',
  'Aliquam consectetur non ipsum sit.']})

df.groupby((~df["ID"].isna()).cumsum()).agg({"ID":"first","Text":".".join})
```

#### input

|  | ID | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 21213 | Voluptatem sed consectetur quisquam est. |
| 1 | nan | Quaerat quisquam modi consectetur. |
| 2 | nan | Est labore aliquam neque quaerat velit labore porro. |
| 3 | 21213 | Dolorem quisquam magnam labore amet amet sit sed. |
| 4 | nan | Magnam ut modi aliquam consectetur quisquam consectetur. |
| 5 | nan | Aliquam consectetur non ipsum sit. |

#### output

| ID | ID | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21213 | Voluptatem sed consectetur quisquam est..Quaerat quisquam modi consectetur..Est labore aliquam neque quaerat velit labore porro. |
| 2 | 21213 | Dolorem quisquam magnam labore amet amet sit sed..Magnam ut modi aliquam consectetur quisquam consectetur..Aliquam consectetur non ipsum sit. |

Comment: Thanks for the Help Rob, But in case if "ID" is in the string format instead of float, the script was not working for me, we need to change any parameter? let's say in place of 21213 I have US21213, in that case how we run this?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['21213a', nan, nan, '21213a', nan, nan],
 'Text': ['Sit neque magnam voluptatem etincidunt labore adipisci sit.',
  'Aliquam voluptatem sit dolor sed dolor.',
  'Non ut aliquam modi amet adipisci est.',
  'Quaerat ipsum ipsum ut est tempora neque.',
  'Porro dolore dolor quiquia consectetur quiquia voluptatem eius.',
  'Dolore dolore porro magnam.']})
` where **ID** is string still works for me